# Logstash not importing Apache log files

Tags: logstash

I am just new to logstash trying to import apache log file into Elastic - I see the below error:
RROR] 2017-10-28 00:38:51.085 [LogStash::Runner] agent - Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 4, column 19 (byte 81) after input {\nfile {\npath =>\"/home/monus/logstash-tutorial-dataset“\nstart_position =>\""}

here is my logstash.conf file

```
filter {
grok {
match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
}
date {
match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's logstash's way of telling you it found a syntax error on line 4, character 19 of the config-file. As line 4 in your snippet is a close-bracket, and you have no `input {}` bracket at all in the snippet, I'd look in your input section for the syntax error.